# Windows Phone Stack Exchange will be archived on November 16, 2022

Tags: discussion, featured, announcement

On November 16th, 2022, the Windows Phone Stack Exchange site will be archived.

### Why now?

After discussing with the site moderators and the Community Team, we concluded that it was time to archive Windows Phone SE. Microsoft announced in 2017 that it would no longer be supporting the Windows Phone OS, and it received its last security update at the end of 2019. In addition to the technology lacking support, activity on the site has dramatically decreased, with very few questions or answers being posted.

### Where will the content go?

All of the content will still be accessible until November 16, 2022. After that point, it will only be accessible via accessing the archive on Area 51. Once the site has been archived, we will make an announcement on Meta Stack Exchange. Please look out for that announcement post on MSE for a chance to reminisce and share memories.

With any of our sites, it takes a lot of work and dedication to function smoothly. We greatly appreciate everyone who participated and contributed to the Windows Phone Stack Exchange site's content and community.

Comment: On behalf of the moderator team, I'd also like to thank everyone who contributed questions, answers, edits, tag wikis, etc., as well as the SE staff members who helped us along the way.